Stop at breakpoint after typing command from debug console on VS Code
I cannot figure out how to make VS Code stop at a breakpoint inside a function after typing a command from Debug Console
I have tried to change launch.json configs to no avail. Breakpoints are working normally when I start debug with F5.
My launch.json:
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Python Debugger: Python File",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}"
    }
]

}
My code:
def myfunc(a,b):
    s = a + b
    return s
print(myfunc(2,3))
    
input("Press Enter to continue debug (or Ctrl+C to exit)...")

Debug console output result:
myfunc(2,3)

5

Expected: stop at breakpoint set at line s = a + b

Hello, what does the error message say? If you add a breakpoint before the code s = a + b and then debug the code. See if it stops at the set breakpoint.

It is stopping at line def myfunc(a,b): if I set a breakpoint there.
I get no error whatsoever, it is just not stopping inside the function

If you add a breakpoint on the line s = a + b. It may stop inside the function.

But it is not stopping:/ any other hints to test this?

This could also be the reason for the configuration chosen when debugging. Whether to select the configuration of Python Debugger: Python File for debugging. What information is output in the output log?

Output log keeps blank

If you try to clear the cache and then restart vscode to reconfigure the launch.json file, will this solve the problem? Or reinstall vscode and follow the steps with the document.
